# spin structures on full flag manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry, complex-geometry

It is known that any full flag manifold $G/T$ is a spin manifold.
For example, we can prove it using that $G/T$ is a complex manifold,
by computing its 1st Chern class as follows: 
For full flag manifolds we have that  the first Chern class is given by
$c_{1}(G/T)= 2\delta_{G} \cdot $ generator of $H^{2}(G/T, \mathbb{Z})$, where $$\delta_{G}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha\in R^{+}}\alpha.$$
Here $R^{+}$ are the postive roots of $G$.
It is well known that  $\delta_{G}=\Lambda_{1}+\cdots+\Lambda_{\ell}$, where $\Lambda_{i}$ are the fundamental weights and $\ell=\dim T= {\rm rank}G$.
Then 
$$ c_{1}(G/T)= 2\delta_{G} \cdot g =2(\Lambda_{1}+\cdots+\Lambda_{\ell}) \cdot g,$$  where $g\in H^{2}(G/T, \mathbb{Z})$ is the generator.   Therefore
$c_{1}(G/T)$ is even and since for a complex manifold $M$ the second Whitney class $w_{2}(M)$
is the reduction $\mod 2$ the first Chern class $c_{1}(M)$, we conclude that 
$$w_{2}(G/T)=0 \ \ thus \ \  G/T \ \  is  \ a \  spin  \ manifold.$$

**Question**   How can we give a proof of  this fact by a different way, for example, by using arguments from homology or cohomology theory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$G/T$ is a co-adjoint orbit in $\mathfrak g^*$.  The normal bundle to the inclusion $G/T\rightarrow \mathfrak g^*$ is trivial, so the tangent bundle of $G/T$ is stably trivial. This implies its Stiefel-Whitney and Pontryagin classes vanish.

(Argument stolen from Dan Freed "Flag Manifolds and Infinite Dimensional Geometry" in MSRI proceedings volume "Infinite Dimensional Groups with Applications".)

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that $G$ is a compact Lie group and $T$ is a maximal torus, right? Let $N$ be the dimension of $G/T$; passing if necessary to a double cover of $G$, you may assume that the isotropy representation $T\rightarrow SO(N)$ lifts to $T\rightarrow Spin(N)$; this gives you a lift of the frame bundle $G\times_T SO(N)$ of $G/T$, to a $Spin(N)$- bundle.

Comment: First chern class of flag variety is positive?